# Inventory source selection to Pickup Order Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, inventory-management

I created Custom Store pickup Shipping Method. Now, After Order Status `Ready for Pickup` I need to **Complete the Order without Creating Shipment**. & also need to **allocate Inventory Source during the Order Complete** Action.

Magento stores Allocated Inventory Source in `inventory_shipment_source` table when Shipment Create Action performs. I am new in Magento & I doesn't get any idea about how to I do **Order Status Complete with Inventory Source allocation to Pickup Order**. Please Help me. I stuck in this topic.

I need to set Order State & Status as a complete, update qty_shipped field of ordered items, & allocate inventory source also to pickup.

my Magento version is **2.4 Community**